# Problems serving static files favicon.ico and robots.txt in CherryPy 3.1

Tags: python, cherrypy

When I try to browse to favicon.ico, for instance, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Static tool requires an absolute filename (got 'favicon.ico')
```

I can get to anything in my /images, /css and /js folders.  Those are serving just fine.  The site looks and acts great.  It's just these darn two files.

Here is my root.conf file.

```
[/]
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.root = "/projects/mysite/root"
tools.staticdir.dir = ""

[/favicon.ico]
tools.staticfile.on = True
tools.staticfile.filename = "favicon.ico"
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = "images"

[/robots.txt]
tools.staticfile.on = True
tools.staticfile.filename = "robots.txt"
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = ""

[/images]
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = "images"

[/css]
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = "css"

[/js]
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = "js"
```

Here is my cherrypy.conf file:

```
[global]
server.socket_port = 8888
server.thread_pool = 10
tools.sessions.on = True
```

Here's my "startweb.py" script:

```
import cherrypy
from root.roothandler import Root

cherrypy.config.update("cherrypy.conf")

cherrypy.tree.mount(Root(), "/", "root/root.conf")

if hasattr(cherrypy.engine, 'block'):
    # 3.1 syntax
    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
else:
    # 3.0 syntax
    cherrypy.server.quickstart()
    cherrypy.engine.start()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you turn on a CherryPy Tool for a particular URL, it's turned on for all "child" URL's below it as well. So the `[/images]`, `[/css]`, and `[/js]` parts of your config seem redundant. So, too, is the `[/robots.txt]` section.

The `[/favicon.ico]` would be redundant, too, except favicon.ico is special because CherryPy sets one for you, typically (as an attribute of your root object; see `_cptree.py`). So overriding it is appropriate:

```
[/]
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.root = "/projects/mysite/trunk/root"
tools.staticdir.dir = ""
tools.staticfile.root = "/projects/mysite/trunk/root"

[/favicon.ico]
tools.staticfile.on = True
tools.staticfile.filename = "images/favicon.ico"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution that works, but I don't like it much.  It requires putting the full, absolute path in 3 places.

Here is the new root.conf

```
[/]
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.root = "/projects/mysite/trunk/root"
tools.staticdir.dir = ""

[/favicon.ico]
tools.staticfile.on = True
tools.staticfile.filename = "/projects/mysite/trunk/root/images/favicon.ico"

[/robots.txt]
tools.staticfile.on = True
tools.staticfile.filename = "/projects/mysite/trunk/root/robots.txt"

[/images]
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = "images"

[/css]
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = "css"

[/js]
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = "js"
```